# .htaccess problem in php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This block is in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

i want to add following block with my .htaccess,
both block run correctly but cant work together

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

SO i want both block into my htaccess so how can i combined it?
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `L` from you first `RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]`. Because `L` is the last rule.

> `'last|L' (last rule)`
>   Stop the rewriting process here and
>   don't apply any more rewriting rules.
>   This corresponds to the Perl `last`
>   command or the `break` command from the
>   C language. Use this flag to prevent
>   the currently rewritten URL from being
>   rewritten further by following rules.
>   For example, use it to rewrite the
>   root-path URL `('/')` to a real one,
>   *e.g.*, `'/e/www/'`.